# Spring boot2 path variable validation

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-boot-2

I am using spring boot for creating rest services. I need to validate the parameter passed. I have a service like below,

```
@GetMapping(value="/employee/{Id}")
public EmployeeDTO getEmployeeDetails(@PathVariable String Id) {
    ...
}
```

I need to throw error if Id is not passed in url. Like "Missing Id in request". I was able to achieve using below,

```
@GetMapping(value={"/employee", "/employee/{Id}"})
public EmployeeDTO getEmployeeDetails(@PathVariable String Id) {
    ...
}
```

And handled MissingPathVariableException in ExceptionHandler annotated with @ControllerAdvise.

But I wanted to know is this the right way to check ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@ControllerAdvise` to handle exceptions that are generated while executing your actual code.

For Path variable validation, you can make use of `spring-boot-starter-validation`.

Add this maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then your controller will look like:

```
@GetMapping(value={"/employee", "/employee/{Id}"})
public EmployeeDTO getEmployeeDetails(
    @NotBlank(message = "Missing Id in request")
    @PathVariable String Id) {
    ...
}
```

I recommend you to read this: [Validating Form Input](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:d1HyUaF4itEJ:https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in)